# TopNavigation Bar is shown Null for Report Centre site in Sharepoint 2007

Tags: development

I have create a Publishing site collection in Sharepoint 2007 and when i try to get the TopNavigation Bar for 'Report Centre' site I get it null.

Why ? However for Document Centre,News etc it is not null. Can someone explain me ?

```
string siteUrl = "http://sp07:9988/sites/testpubsite/Reports";
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteUrl))
{
    SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
    var topBar = web.Navigation.TopNavigationBar;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply because it might be that your Top Link bar is INHERITED from its parent. Check also for the UseShared if its TRUE then the reference shall always be NULL.

See here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.navigation.spnavigation.topnavigationbar.aspx